# PHP $_POST form with $_GET after submit

Tags: php, html, forms

I use PHP.

I have a form and after submit I want it to go to a URL with a $_POST variable at the end (as a $_GET), like this:

```
http://example.com/page.php?my_key=my_value
```

The problem is that "my_value" is created witin the form which means it does not know about it before the form is posted. Any ideas?

```
<form method="post" action="/page.php?my_key=">
    <input type="text" value="my_value" name="my_key">
    <input type="submit" name="submitter">
</form>
```

Comment: you can't do that - the form has to be all get or all post. You can modify the action attribute however.

Comment: You may get away with using `$_REQUEST['var'];` in your PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After sending form in PHP you can simple make 302 redirection to url you want.

In PHP file page.php (or in other file that is front controller)  you can simple do:

```
if (isset($_POST['my_key'])) {
    header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$_POST['my_key'],true,302);
}
```

Comment: I've used it at least twice and the best is you should not worry for users who have JavaScript disabled

Answer (score 1):

Use Javascript to change the `action` attribute.

I.E. Using jQuery:

```
jQuery('form').submit(function(eve) {
    var action = eve.target.attr('action');
    action = action + eve.target.find('input[name="my_key"]').val();
    eve.target.attr('action',action);
});
```

A little rough, needs to be checked and maybe debugged.

Answer (score 1):

You can Not pass an POST value through an url :
what you can do is something like this:

```
<form action="/page.php?my_key=" name="pre" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="my_key" value="my_value">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout("document.forms['pre'].submit();",0);
</script>
```

now this will act as an link and will auto submit form as an POST.